What is holding Arrakis captive?
Jessica, Paul's mother, drank the Water of Life and survived, fulfilling a prophecy.
Chani attributes her survival to her own people's writing, implying it was not a miracle.
Stilgar, however, believes it is a miracle and a fulfillment of the prophecy, calling
Chani's skepticism "blasphemy":

Shishakil: The Mahdi must be Fremen!
Chani: Arrakis must be freed by its own people!
She's right. She's right!

What is holding Arrakis captive?

Have you finished watching the movie? It's quite clear what is holding Arrakis captive.

The Imperium is holding Arrakis (and by extension, its people) captive. Kynes Sr. describes it thusly to his son.

“Arrakis is a one-crop planet,” his father said. “One crop. It
supports a ruling class that lives as ruling classes have lived in all
times while, beneath them, a semihuman mass of semislaves exists on
the leavings. It’s the masses and the leavings that occupy our
attention. These are far more valuable than has ever been suspected.”
“I’m ignoring you, Father,” Kynes whispered. “Go away.”
And he thought: Surely there must be some of my Fremen near. They
cannot help but see the birds over me. They will investigate if only
to see if there’s moisture available.
“The masses of Arrakis will know that we work to make the land flow
with water,” his father said. “Most of them, of course, will have only
a semimystical understanding of how we intend to do this. Many, not
understanding the prohibitive mass-ratio problem, may even think we’ll
bring water from some other planet rich in it. Let them think anything
they wish as long as they believe in us.“

Critically, the Spacing Guild prevents the use of weather satellites to make the planet livable and the removal of Spice other than by the Emperor's placeman.

When Chani is speaking of Arrakis, she means the Fremen should be in control of the planet and free from subjugation by the Empire and the Harkonnen governors.

Not just the Harkonnen. There have been a succession of Imperial appointees. The Harkonnen have only been in place for 80-ish years, barely an eyeblink.
